# Add macro with variable via cmake

Tags: c, cmake, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to add macro to file via cmake, and when I do

```
   set_source_files_properties(path_to_file
        PROPERTIES
        COMPILE_FLAGS "-Dfoo=bar"
        )
```

everything is ok, macro is defined, but

```
set_source_files_properties(path_to_file
            PROPERTIES
            COMPILE_FLAGS "-Dfoo(x)=bar(x)"
            )
```

I'm getting an error "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected".

Is it possible to add macro with variable via cmake file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should protect the commandline with quotes:

```
'-Dfoo(x)=bar(x)'
```

Comment: I've tried it, but forget to mention. I updated my question.

Comment: You should single quotes to avoid parsing